# I'm not understanding something at PHP handling

Tags: php, html, event-handling

i'm new to programming so sorry if this question doesn't makes much sense.I learned PHP handling and i succeed at it. But i am not able to do something.
First take a look at the code...

```
<body>

<form action="get.php" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit"value="Connect" class="btn">
</form>
<>
</body>
</html>
```

And the get.php file:

```
<html>
<body>

Connected to: <?php echo $_GET["name"];?><br>


</body>
</html>
```

The output (connected to $name) will be on a blank page, without the other html and css elements. Is there a way to print the output right below the connect button ?

Comment: You need to look into javascript. And ajax if you need to contact the server, for example to validate a username / password combination.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best approach in modern web programming, but since you're a beginner: you can combine the PHP connection logic with the HTML into the same file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="get">
     Username: <input type="text" name="name" />
     <input type="submit" value="Connect" class="btn" />
</form>
<?php
     if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
          echo "Connected to: " . $_GET["name"];
     }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I omitted the `action="..."`, in order to target to the current page.

By the way, a good approach will be to separate the business logic from the visual components (I recommend you to read about the MVC design pattern).

In addition, if you want to obviate refreshing the whole page, you can use JavaScript and AJAX (I recommend you to read about jQuery), but it's a bit more advanced.

Comment: form action is the current page by default, you don't need a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

The web is "stateless" and what it sounds like you want to do is to submit the form without refreshing the page.  This can be done client side in JavaScript.  The following for instance uses jQuery to make the JS you have to write smaller, but can (arguably should) done in straight JS.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="get.php" method="get" id="the-form">
      <label for="name">Username: <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
      <br>
      <input type="submit"value="Connect" class="btn">
    </form>
    <div id="response">
      <?php
        if(isset($_GET['name']))
        {
          include('get.php');
        }
      ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(#the-form).submit(function(event) 
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'get.php',
      type: 'get',
      data: $("#the-form").serialize(),
      success: function(data)
      {
        $('#response').append(data);                
      }
    });
  });      
</script>
```

If you're not worried about the page refresh, then Reflection's answer is what you are looking for.  That said, you could do both using the JS/ajax free version as a fall back and the AJAX version as a progressive enhancement.